# How to fix deprecated create_function

Tags: wordpress, deprecated, php-7.2, create-function

We have recently updated our Wordpress to work with `PHP 7.2`. After having a few issues I have turned on the debug to see that most of the issue is deprecated code.

I am not a coder but I have look through the forums and found a couple of answers. The following is what I am stuck on and can't figure out.

**CODE 1**

```
if ( file_exists( self::$_plugin_path . '/controllers/activation.php' ) ) {
    $escaped_plugin_path = preg_replace( '#^\\\\\\\\#', '\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\', self::$_plugin_path );
    register_activation_hook( self::$_plugin_path . '/' . pb_backupbuddy::settings( 'init' ), create_function( '', "require_once('" . 
}
```

**CODE 2**

```
$section_callback = create_function('', 'echo "' . $desc . '";');
```

**CODE 3**

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', create_function( '',
"wp_enqueue_style( 'pb_backupbuddy-wp-admin', '" . pb_backupbuddy::plugin_url() . "/css/wp-admin.css', array(), pb_backupbuddy::settings( 'version' ) );"
)
```

I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

**CODE 1: register_activation_hook**

```
register_activation_hook( self::$_plugin_path . '/' . pb_backupbuddy::settings( 'init' ), function() { require_once(); } );
```

**CODE 2:**

```
$section_callback = function() {
    echo $desc;
};
```

**CODE 3:**

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function() { wp_enqueue_style( 'pb_backupbuddy-wp-admin', pb_backupbuddy::plugin_url().'/css/wp-admin.css', pb_backupbuddy::settings( 'version' ) ); } );
```